# JS ES6 class definition: Example on Preact homepage: I've never seen this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, preact

The following example is on the [Preact homepage](https://preactjs.com/).  I'm wondering how/why there are equals `=` assignments and semicolons `;` within the class curly braces `{}`.  I've googled for a few minutes, and can't seem to figure it out.

Is this TypeScript or some other fancy JS cousin?  The curly braces look like regular assignments, not a class definition.

```
export default class TodoList extends Component {
    state = { todos: [], text: '' };
    setText = e => {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
    };
    addTodo = () => {
        let { todos, text } = this.state;
        todos = todos.concat({ text });
        this.setState({ todos, text: '' });
    };
    render({ }, { todos, text }) {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.addTodo} action="javascript:">
                <input value={text} onInput={this.setText} />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
                <ul>
                    { todos.map( todo => (
                        <li>{todo.text}</li>
                    )) }
                </ul>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say cousin or incorporates a pre-processor. variable assignments within the class definition isn't _entirely_ out of the question (class member variables; IIRC ES7 has something similar) but that inline html can be returned is definitely not something I'd consider part of standard ES6+.

Comment: @XerenNarcy the inline HTML is just JSX.

Comment: @XerenNarcy: ES7 (ES2016) certainly doesn't have that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [class instance fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) (property initializers). They are currently stage 2 proposal.

Their use (alongside with `import`, `export` and other features that aren't supported by JS engines natively) implies that Babel is supposed to be used to transpile the example.